# React js get Table data on button click

Tags: reactjs, select, event-handling, material-ui, onchange

how do I  get Table data on button click in React js

My Code to bind table data is

```
item.map(k => (
    <TableRow >
        <TableCell >{k.key}</TableCell>
        {
            k.val.map(r => (
                <TableRow >
                <TableCell>{r}</TableCell>
                </TableRow> 
    
            ))
        }
        <TableCell >
            <select  onChange={this.getListID} >
                <option value="noImport" >Dont import</option>
                {
                    item && item.map(k => <option key={k.key} value={k.key}>{k.key}</option>)
                }
            </select>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>     
  ))
}
```

table rows comes like this

[image]

I have seen example but in that Button is included in row . i want to fetch entire table all rows..

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

On the click of a button, you can call the API to get all the data and then store that data in some new variable and iterate through the variable.

You can call the API using axios. I would suggest you use a store where you can store the data coming from axios and then easily iterate through it.

Comment: The example for this will become bigger to be typed here. Please refer to articles where they have used Axios and then refer to article where they show how to use redux in the application. Later, you can refer thunk to be used which can easily support async calls using Axios and store update using redux.

Comment: provide some specific articles , i dont want full code , just specific code on button click to get data back from table